# Rust equivalent of Java Consumer interface for Strategy pattern

Tags: java, rust, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I will provide a practical example.

I want to create an event logger. I define an event as an Interface:

```java
import java.util.function.Consumer;

interface Event {}

class BuyEvent implements Event {}

class SellEvent implements Event {}
```

A logger is simply a Consumer of events:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Consumer<Event> logger;

        // Logger with method reference
        logger = System.out::println;
        logger.accept(new BuyEvent());

        // Logger with lambda
        logger = (event) -> {
            // Do something else
            System.out.println(event);
        };
        logger.accept(new BuyEvent());
```

I can also create a logger with state. For example:

```java
class StatefulLogger implements Consumer<Event> {
    public StatefulLogger() {
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(Event event) {
        // Change state, then print event
        System.out.println(event);
    }
}
```

I can use the stateful logger as follows:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Consumer<Event> logger = new StatefulLogger("foo.txt");
        logger.accept(new BuyEvent());
}
```

I am trying to achieve the same in Rust.

I define an event as an enum:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Event {
    BuyEvent,
    SellEvent,
}
```

I define a Logger trait and a struct with state that implements such trait:

```rust
trait Logger {
    fn accept(&mut self, ev: Event);
}

struct StatefulLogger {}

impl Logger for StatefulLogger {
    fn accept(&mut self, ev: Event) {
        // Change state, then print event
        println!("{:?}", ev);
    }
}
```

I can use the logger as follows:

```rust
fn main() {
    let logger: &dyn Logger = &ComplexLogger {};
}
```

I would like to be able to assign a closure to the logger, much in the same spirit of Java.

```rust
fn main() {
    let consumer: fn(Event) = |ev: Event| {
        println!("{:?}", ev);
    };
}
```

To recap:

In Java, I had implemented a logger using a Strategy design pattern using the Consumer interface. A logger could both be a complex stateful object but also a lightweight lambda.

I would like to achieve the same in Rust, but I don't know how to proceed. I was not able to find similar examples on the Internet. Also, does Rust provide an analogous to Java's Consumer interface?

Comment: Are you looking for the [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html)/`FnMut`/`FnOnce` traits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to solve this fast in Rust, but you can create own macro to convert lambda to Logger impl and then return its object. Have a look at this [repo](https://github.com/mystor/lambda-macro). If you want, I can write a solution soon.
In other way you can change your `Logger trait` to struct, where define field for consumer. It gives you possibility to use as consumer any `Fn(Event)` i.e if you have logger with state, you can move it to lambda and pass it or pass some fn directly.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Event;

struct Logger<T>
where
    T: Fn(Event),
{
    consumer: T,
}

impl<T> Logger<T>
where
    T: Fn(Event),
{
    fn new(consumer: T) -> Self {
        Self { consumer }
    }

    fn accept(&self, event: Event) {
        (self.consumer)(event);
    }
}

struct StatefulLogger;

impl StatefulLogger {
    fn log(&self, event: Event) {
        println!("{:?}", event);
    }
}

fn log_fn(e: Event) {
    println!("{:?}", e);
}

fn main() {
    let foo = |e: Event| println!("{:?}", e);
    let logger_lambda = Logger::new(foo);

    let stateful_logger = StatefulLogger;
    let logger_struct = Logger::new(move |e| stateful_logger.log(e));

    let logger_fn = Logger::new(log_fn);

    logger_lambda.accept(Event);
    logger_struct.accept(Event);
    logger_fn.accept(Event);
}
```

About consumer interface, have a look on Fn, FnMut and FnOnce traits.